# WPF TwoWay Binding not work with CustomControl in Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, binding

I have some problems with my Custom Control - Two way binding don't work when I use it in template.
So I have created template xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
                xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:GUIControls;assembly=GUIControls"
                >

  <ResourceDictionary 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
                xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:GUIControls;assembly=GUIControls"
                >

<ControlTemplate x:Key="YParamCombo" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <controls:ParamCombo Header="MY CONTROL TEMPLATE"
    Items="{Binding Items}"
    PCValue="{Binding Codes[MY_CONTROL_TEMPLATE], Mode=TwoWay}"
    Required="True"
    MultiSelect="False"/>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="YComboBox" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <ComboBox       DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    StaysOpenOnEdit="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Codes[STANDARD_TEMPLATE], Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="Code"/> 
</ControlTemplate>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:GUIControls;assembly=GUIControls"
Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="525">

<Grid Margin="0,0,0,-1">
    <Button Margin="62,162,299,4" Content="Show Codes-1" Click="Button_Click2"></Button>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <HeaderedContentControl Header="STANDARD CONTROL XAML" >
            <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                StaysOpenOnEdit="True" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                SelectedValue="{Binding Codes[STANDARD_XAML]}"
                SelectedValuePath="Code"/>
        </HeaderedContentControl>
        <HeaderedContentControl Header="STANDARD CONTROL TEMPLATE" >
            <ContentControl Height="23" Template="{StaticResource YComboBox}"/>
        </HeaderedContentControl>
        <ContentControl Height="44" Template="{StaticResource YParamCombo}">
        </ContentControl>
        <controls:ParamCombo Header="MY CONTROL XAML"
            Items="{Binding Items}"
            PCValue="{Binding Codes[MYCONTROL_XAML], Mode=TwoWay}"
            Required="True"
            MultiSelect="False"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = new WModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private WModel vm { get { return (DataContext as WModel); } }
        private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Join(";", vm.Codes._codes.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value).ToArray()));
        }
    }
}

using GUIControls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class WModel
    {
        public WModel()
        {
            Codes = new CodesClass();
        }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Dict> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return new ObservableCollection<Dict>()
                {
                    new Dict(){ Name = "Name1",  Code = "Code1"  } ,
                    new Dict(){ Name = "Name2",  Code = "Code2"  }
                };
            }
        }
        public CodesClass Codes { get; set; }
    }
    public class Dict : IDict
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
    public class CodesClass
    {
        public Dictionary<string, object> _codes;
        public CodesClass()
        {
            _codes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
        public object this[string param]
        {
            get
            {
                if (_codes.ContainsKey(param))
                    return _codes[param];
                else
                    return null;//  "I have no " + param;
            }
            set
            {
                _codes[param] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run app and select all 4 comboboxes and Press button, I can see that twoway binding in one combobox(Custom Control declared in template ) do not work

```
---------------------------

---------------------------
STANDARD_XAML=Code2;STANDARD_TEMPLATE=Code2;MYCONTROL_XAML=Code2
---------------------------
ОК   
---------------------------
```

Some code from control

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PCValueProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("PCValue", typeof(string), typeof(ParamCombo),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPCValuePropertyChanged)));
    //new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValuePropertyChanged)));, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPCValuePropertyChanged))
    #endregion

    private static void OnPCValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ParamCombo paramCombo = (ParamCombo)sender;
        paramCombo.UpdateSelected((e.NewValue == null) ? "" : e.NewValue.ToString());
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no need to **scream** (bold letters = screaming) but to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for a working binding

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it bold I only copied text of message box window.

Comment: @IlyaFetisov I fixed it for you. Please fix it yourself next time.

Comment: Thanks.
I didn' really understand how I should implement INotifyPropertyChanged  for Custom Control and how it should help me. I should assign PropertyChange event in my template?

Comment: The controls already have a notification mechanism implemented (DependencyProperty). But your WModel, Dict, CodeClass don‘t have that. When you implement INotifyPropertyChanged on that classes it should work (well CodeClass with the dictionary is problematic). There are thousands of examples out in the web how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: So why this all works good with standard combobox?
INotifyPropertyChanged (as I think) - should notify control about changes - So control refresh itself in UI. But here is absolutly different situation. Value changed in control but not saved in binded object. I didn't find in web any samle of Custom Control with fully custom property with databinding (all properties in samples works thru Templatebinding in Generic.xaml, I think using some inside magic)

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with twoway binding in a combo in a customcontrol template and the solution was to override OnApplyTemplate in the custom control, using Template.FindName to get the combo, get the DataContex object of the combo and raise PropertyChanged in the DataContext object for the bound property. My problem was to update the combo when the window was loaded.